# Java Multithreading basic questions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the below questions in java multithreading

In Java Multithreading , all threads share the same piece of java code and executes them parallely?

Or Java piece of code shared by each thread is different?

Comment: Re *"Also I read..."* Where did you read this? Can you post word for word what you read as well as the source, as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `"Also I read that at a time only one thread can run.. So if this statement is true then where are achieving multithreading?"` -- again, please show us where you read this.

Comment: Yes . Pls click this link  http://www.javatpoint.com/sleep()-method                              As you know well that at a time only one thread is executed. If you sleep a thread for the specified time,the thread shedular picks up another thread and so on.

Comment: `"As you know well that at a time only one thread is executed."` -- this I don't know well, and in fact I always thought that this was the whole point of threading -- to allow multiple threads of program flow to execute **simultaneously**. Also your link doesn't support your statement about "only one thread can run". I strongly believe that your statement is in error.

Comment: Correction, it does state that, but it's grossly in error. Do not believe anything that that author writes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the purpose of multithreading is to allow the threads to execute _concurrently_.  Concurrency is not the same thing as simultaneity.  Multi-threading has been used on single-processor machines dating back at least to the 1970's (E.g., MIT Lisp Machines.)

Comment: You tell a thread what code to execute when you start it.  E.g., in Java, a new thread executes the `run()` method of a given `Runnable` object.  Two threads will execute the same code if the program _gives_ them the same code.  They will run different code if the program gives them different code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes Threads would be executing the same piece of code but if your code contains shared class level variables then it needs to be properly synchronised so that the each thread reads a consistent state of variables.

Threading is to ensure concurrent access to a piece of code via multiple threads.

There are different ways to achieve thread safety. You can refer java concurrency is practice for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are only executed in parallel on multiprocessors (one thread per CPU).
On single processor machines, threading is performed to use the idle time of CPU.